# Change date string format with datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to use datetime to normalize the 'Date' column of a dataframe. The column has multiple dates in the follwing format

```
31-Dec-2019:07:30:03
```

I'm trying to change it to be

```
12-31-2019 07:30:03
```

I tried to do this

```
access_log['date1'] = [datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S') for x in access_log['Date'] ]
```

but I keep getting an error saying `time data '31-Dec-2019:07:30:03' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'`. Is there something I'm doing wrong. How can I fix this?

Comment: do: `pd.to_datetime(access_log['date1']).dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')`?

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm getting an error ParserError: Unknown string format: 31-Dec-2019:07:30:03

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to dateutil library.

https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/

```
    from dateutil import parser
    parser.parse("datestr")
```

Just be aware that if you have a large data amount this might by not the most optimal way to approach the problem tho.